# "LV Status NOT available" after converting root from lvm2 to lvm2+raid1 (lvconvert --type raid1)

Tags: raid, lvm, boot, raid1

I just converted by lvm2 root filesystem from linear lvm2 (single HDD:sda) to lvm2 raid1 (using `lvconvert  -m1 --type raid1 /dev/ubuntu/root /dev/sdb5` command). But after this conversion I can't boot my ubuntu 12.10 (kernel 3.5.0-17-generic).

Initramfs says that it can't find root fs in /dev/mapper:

```
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
... (kernel messages)
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!
```

There is my list of modules and cmdline:

```
(initramfs) cat /proc/modules
hid_generic
usbhid
hid
e1000
raid10
raid456
async_pq
async_xor
xor
async_memcpy
async_raid6_recov
raid6_pq
async_tx
raid1
raid0
multipath
linear
(initramfs) cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinux-3.5.0-17-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root ro
(initramfs) ls /dev/mapper
control     ubuntu-swap_1
```

There is output from `lvm` utility, which says that root LV is inactive / NOT available:

```
lvm> pvscan
  PV /dev/sda5    VG ubuntu   lvm2 [ 13.76 GiB / 408.00 MiB free]
  PV /dev/sdb5    VG ubuntu   lvm2 [ 13.76 GiB / 508.00 MiB free]
lvm> vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
  Found volume group "ubuntu" using metadata type lvm2
lvm> lvscan
  inactive        '/dev/ubuntu/root' [13.26 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE          '/dev/ubuntu/swap_1' [100.00 MiB] inherit

lvm> lvdisplay ubuntu
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu
  LV UUID                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2013-05-07
  LV Status              NOT available          <<<<< !!!!
  LV Size                13.26 GB
  Current LE             3394
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

And `lvchange -ay ubuntu` fails from initrd in my case:

```
lvm>  lvchange -ay ubuntu
  /sbin/modprobe failed: 1
  Can't process LV root: raid1 target support missing from kernel?
```

Which module is missing in my initrd? Now I have full collection of modules from this kernel and can try any module.

Comment: did you recreate initrd after the conversion?

Comment: ptman, no, I didn't. Only waited for full resync. Do you think, that `update-initramfs -u` will include dm-raid into initrd?

Comment: update-initramfs didn't include dm-raid into image; I needed to manually add this module to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
modprobe dm_raid
```

`{pv,vg,lv}scan` have a look at the disk and see the LVs there. But as the kernel cannot provide access to them in the configured way they are not available for access.

Comment: insmod dm_raid helped but I still needed to do `lvchange -ay ubuntu` to boot.

Comment: @osgx Sure. The kernel module **enables** you to make the `lvchange` call. That was your problem, wasn't it? It doesn't **replace** the call. If it did, all VGs would always be (or at least start) active.

Comment: Hauke, my first problem was that I can't boot after lvconvert. Part of it - is that i have no dm-raid module in initramfs.

Comment: @osgx I meant "the problem you asked for" as you had already tracked the solution of your bigger problem down to a missing kernel module.